# jQuery slow movement of content below a fadeOut()

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to fade out content. The problem is that the content below the fadeOut gets pushed instantly into place (rather than a smooth transition).

So for example, I'd like to fade out this box, and have the paragraph below it move smoothly into its new position. How can I do this?

```
div {
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
background-color: #FA6900;
border-radius: 5px;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
      $('div').fadeOut('slow');
     });
});
```

http://codepen.io/SeanPeterson/pen/MbOYyb

Thanks!

Comment: How about `.slideUp()` instead of `.fadeOut()`?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: Or pass a value to `hide()` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVaERw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a .slideUp() in place of your .fadeOut()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
  $('div').slideUp('slow');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trick. In your HTML, wrap your `div` into another one:

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
#div2 {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #FA6900;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#div1{
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

And your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
      $('#div2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $("#div1").slideUp("slow")
      });
    });
});
```

**Explanation**
When you wrap your main div into another one with `height` and `width` set you have two identical `div`'s but one has no background which makes it invisible. Now when you `fadeOut` the inner `div`, the outter stays the same, until `.fadeOut()` is finished. Then the callback function is fired and outer div slides up, which makes the paragraph smoothly slide up

Answer (score 0):

What about css i.e class transitions?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){

      if(!$(".hideme").hasClass("hidden")){
        
        $('.hideme').addClass('hidden');
        
      }else{
      
         $('.hideme').removeClass('hidden');
      
      }


    });
});
```

```css
.hideme {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #FA6900;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition:500ms;
}

.hideme.hidden{

  height:0;
  opacity:0;
  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICKME</button>
<div class="hideme"></div>  
        <p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mollis volutpat nisl, id placerat tortor volutpat sed. Nullam tempor magna sodales, interdum lacus eget, elementum purus. Cras quis sagittis ipsum, at finibus lacus. Morbi sit amet gravida sem. Integer sed libero at neque varius blandit a vitae nunc. Phasellus pellentesque augue elit, vitae convallis est venenatis eget. Maecenas dictum aliquet accumsan. Donec sed arcu arcu.

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ultricies, orci eu maximus porta, ipsum urna sollicitudin dolor, blandit lacinia diam risus vel lorem. Maecenas bibendum ut augue id eleifend. Donec orci metus, posuere vitae sem nec, vehicula aliquet neque. Vivamus mattis mauris leo, et malesuada lectus placerat eu. Cras sit amet suscipit mauris. Fusce at finibus ex. Duis ac molestie urna. Etiam sodales iaculis leo, eu semper massa placerat sed. Cras at odio sodales, tristique odio vitae, hendrerit ex.

Praesent condimentum dignissim tellus dignissim dapibus. Duis ex velit, ullamcorper at felis vel, aliquet iaculis ligula. In egestas, ante a blandit tempor, ante mauris sodales lacus, nec pretium augue ipsum sagittis elit. Proin elementum ante non lacus ultrices, quis varius metus rhoncus. Suspendisse accumsan, libero at ultrices vehicula, lacus nisi imperdiet nisi, nec ultrices orci est vitae quam. Curabitur aliquam enim tortor, eget sodales arcu hendrerit in. Vivamus eu ultricies purus. Nulla lobortis vitae metus ac luctus. Vivamus maximus eros a rutrum dictum. Etiam non faucibus leo, aliquet condimentum ligula. Donec nec pulvinar enim, ut finibus mauris. Nam nunc nibh, congue eu felis tincidunt, euismod ornare lectus. Vestibulum sit amet mattis elit.

Aenean vitae feugiat nibh, sed consequat ligula. Etiam consequat at nisi nec venenatis. Ut lobortis nec tortor id gravida. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin rhoncus efficitur augue, at dapibus purus sollicitudin vitae. Maecenas sapien dui, pretium ut justo et, accumsan finibus justo. Integer eu quam id tellus tincidunt egestas. In ornare a dolor ut elementum. Etiam ut dui id purus malesuada vehicula.

Nulla sed venenatis sapien. Proin varius tortor urna, at varius enim lobortis quis. Proin consequat id augue sit amet molestie. Quisque molestie tristique pellentesque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin suscipit mauris nec iaculis iaculis. Maecenas fermentum eget erat vitae consequat. Maecenas in dui id augue pulvinar fermentum id in augue. Duis ullamcorper dapibus lectus ullamcorper congue. Vivamus ultricies felis eu arcu efficitur, non tincidunt felis varius. Donec purus lectus, efficitur ac ex sit amet, dignissim rhoncus lorem. </p>
```